# CGPoint Scalar Multiplication Swift

Tags: math, swift

I am building a platformer game in SpriteKit and was going to implement an update function for my entities so they would move according to gravity and their velocity. However, I need to make the amount of velocity added proportional to delta time to prevent frame rate from affecting how my entities move, so I was going to import GLKit so I could use the scalar functions. However swift is not compatible. Is there some other way of implementing scalar multiply to CGPoints or making velocity propositional to delta time?

PS: Could someone also explain what scalar multiply is and how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way of doing math with `CGPoint`s. There are many third party libraries that do this, mostly built in the pre-`GLKit` days. As you mentioned, the best way of doing this now is with `GLKit`, when it supports Swift. Hopefully soon.

Scalar multiplication is super easy. You just need to multiply each component of the `CGPoint` with the same number (also called scalars).

```
CGPoint CGPointMultiplyScalar(CGPoint point, CGFloat scalar) {
    return CGPointMake(point.x * scalar, point.y * scalar);
}
```